# iPod/iTunes Artists show splitted!

Tags: itunes, audio, ipod

I have OST mp3 albums with songs from one to multiple artists. For example, please consider the artists tags as below:

- Album1.File1 - Artist1
- Album1.File2 - Artist2, Artist1
- Album1.File3 - Artist2, Artist3
- Album1.File4 - Artist2
- Album2.File1 - Artist4
- Album2.File2 - Artist1, Artist3
- Album2.File3 - Artist2, Artist4
- Album2.File4 - Artist3

Now, when I sync my iPod with iTunes, I see in iPod Music Artists list like:

- Artist1 (1 file)
- Artist2 (1 file)
- Artist3 (1 file)
- Artist4 (1 file)
- Artist1, Artist3 (1 file)
- Artist2, Artist4 (1 file)
- Artist2, Artist1 (1 file)
- Artist2, Artist3 (1 file)

Now, my question is can we have the Artist name separated and show all files that they are included in? That is something like following:

- Artist1 (3 files)
- Artist2 (4 files)
- Artist3 (3 files)
- Artist4 (1 file)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks,
-V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, no. iTunes doesn't have the ability to tell the difference between multiple artists. All it does is group songs with similar text. It doesn't have the ability to read commas or the like. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I found similar answer at http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11656777&#11656777

I wonder why iTunes doesn't have this feature :-(

Comment: It's actually something they'd have to program in and create a whole new system. Kind of like the tag system over here at SuperUser. Who knows, they might eventually develop it.